# godaddy office 365 smtp settings in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, office365, actionmailer

I`m using this smtp configuration:

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.office365.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'mydomain.com',
  authentication:       :login,
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name:            'myname@mydomain.com',
  password:             'password'
}
```

But this results in:

*Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501 5.1.7 Invalid address [MMXP12301MB1519.GBRP123.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]*

Do you know what is wrong with this configuration?

P.S. *Googling the error and all kinds of configurations didnt help.*

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling for a long time. I ultimately had the following settings:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    user_name:      ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'],
    password:       ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
    from:           ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'],
    address:        'smtp.office365.com',
    port:           '587',
    authentication: 'login',
}
```

where the STMP_USERNAME and STMP_PASSWORD are the username and password for your GoDaddy Office 365 email you are sending the email from. The domain was also causing me some issues. When I removed it, everything worked. I don't know if this addresses your problem, but it worked for me and will hopefully work for you